# Помогите с реидректом htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно сделать редирект со страницы item/всё что угодно на details/всё что угодно.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не лучший вариант, так-как используется URL, а не относительный путь, но лучше что-то не нагуглил.

```
Redirect 301 /item/ http://example.com/details/
```

301 — код редиректа.

Предполагается что /item это http://example.com/item

Comment: На будущее: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html